# How can I get the console logs from the iOS Simulator?

Tags: ios, console, ios-simulator

I want to see what happens in the iOS Simulator if I'm not testing the app in Xcode.

For example, if I open a link in the Safari simulator, see what happens in the console,
or if I install a web-app, see the links that I'm pressing in console.

How can I do this?

I want to see it in Xcode or Terminal, but it's not a problem if I need to use another bit of software.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29310542/59087

Answer (score 317, accepted):

iOS Simulator > Menu Bar > Debug > Open System Log

---

Old ways:

iOS Simulator prints its logs directly to stdout, so you can see the logs mixed up with system logs.

Open the Terminal and type: `tail -f /var/log/system.log`

Then run the simulator.

EDIT:

This stopped working on Mavericks/Xcode 5. Now you can access the simulator logs in its own folder: `~/Library/Logs/iOS Simulator/<sim-version>/system.log`

You can either use the Console.app to see this, or just do a tail (iOS 7.0.3 64 bits for example):

`tail -f ~/Library/Logs/iOS\ Simulator/7.0.3-64/system.log`

EDIT 2:

They are now located in `~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/<simulator-hash>/system.log`

`tail -f ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/<simulator-hash>/system.log`

Comment: Is this still accurate? I'm not seeing anything from `console.log` in these log using `tail` or `Console.app`

Comment: I am not getting any results either on OSX 10.10. those logs are there but my simulator is version 8.1 and the logs all are versions 7.1*

Comment: iOS Simulator > Menu Bar > Debug > Open System Log

Comment: Thanks! Its ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/<simulator-hash>/system.log these days though.

Comment: The answer from BYossarian is the "correct" one. "Develop menu in desktop safari that lets you see the iOS simulator console:

Develop -> iPhone Simulator -> site name"

Comment: In case you're unsure of what `<simulator-hash>` to use (I was), you can also simply do: `tail -f ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/*/system.log` which would render all but keep on tailing only the one that gets updated (most likely the running one)

Comment: If you use fastlane, I added support for this in the 'scan' action in the Fastlane toolset: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/releases/tag/2.9.0

Comment: Sorry, this log is almost empty for me, it should be polluted with many system messages similar to logcat on Android.

Comment: Only the other answer worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/14415709/1740008

Answer (score 266):

You can view the console for the iOS Simulator via desktop Safari. It's similar to the way you use desktop Safari to view the console for physical iOS devices.

Whenever the simulator is running and there's a webpage open, there'll be an option under the Develop menu in desktop safari that lets you see the iOS simulator console:

Develop -> iPhone Simulator -> *site name*

Comment: Note that you need a device or the Simulator running iOS >= 6. You also may have to enable Web Inspector support on iOS (Settings App > Safari > Advanced).

Comment: Looks like is now just: Develop > Simulator > (your simulator name)

Comment: I had to first open the Simulator, and then restart Safari in order to get the option this answer describes. But then it worked like a charm.

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me. Also you have first to enable that Develop menu going to: Preferences > Advanced > [Check] Show Develop menu in menu bar.

Answer (score 120):

There's an option in the Simulator to open the `console`

```
Debug > Open System Log
```

or use the 

`keyboard shortcut: ⌘/`

[image: Simulator menu screenshot]

Answer (score 95):

## iOS 8 and iOS 9

Under iOS 8 and iOS 9 this location is now:

```
~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/<DEVICE_CODE>
```

So, the following will work:

```
tail -f ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/<DEVICE_CODE>/system.log
```

The `DEVICE_CODE` value can be found via the following terminal command:

```
instruments -s devices
```

Comment: To find the device identifier: in Xcode, click Windows > Devices. A device and the identifier will be displayed in the right-hand pane.

Comment: You can type ```instruments -s devices``` in the console

Comment: s/console/terminal window/

Comment: This didn't work for me.  `xcrun simctl spawn booted log stream --level=debug | grep App_Debug_String` worked.

Comment: @viteinfinite `instruments` command not found. Where is `instruments` located?

Answer (score 47):

You should not rely on `instruments -s`. The officially supported tool for working with Simulators from the command line is `xcrun simctl`.

The log directory for a device can be found with `xcrun simctl getenv booted SIMULATOR_LOG_ROOT`. This will always be correct even if the location changes.

Now that things are moving to `os_log` it is easier to open Console.app on the host Mac. Booted simulators should show up as a log source on the left, just like physical devices. You can also run log commands in the booted simulator:

```
# os_log equivalent of tail -f
xcrun simctl spawn booted log stream --level=debug

# filter log output
xcrun simctl spawn booted log stream --predicate 'processImagePath endswith "myapp"'
xcrun simctl spawn booted log stream --predicate 'eventMessage contains "error" and messageType == info'

# a log dump that Console.app can open
xcrun simctl spawn booted log collect

# open location where log collect will write the dump
cd `xcrun simctl getenv booted SIMULATOR_SHARED_RESOURCES_DIRECTORY`
```

**If you want to use Safari Developer tools (including the JS console) with a webpage in the Simulator**: Start one of the simulators, open Safari, then go to Safari on your mac and you should see Simulator in the menu.

You can open a URL in the Simulator by dragging it from the Safari address bar and dropping on the Simulator window. You can also use `xcrun simctl openurl booted <url>`.

Comment: This is the correct answer now as of Xcode 9.3, iOS 11.  The locations mentioned in other answers is no longer correct.

Comment: This worked for me on Xcode Version 10.1 (10B61), iOS 12.1 Simulator. Using it to view iOS app console output in Emacs. Other answers worked in the past, but no longer.

Comment: For me, the thing that worked was the order (I had Safari open before the Simulator and so the menu entry did not appear in Safari)!

Comment: Where did you find the documentation for the "predicate" flag?

Comment: New to macOS 11 and iOS 14 simulators: `log help predicates` will give you more information. The predicate format follows NSPredicate.

Comment: This is the best answer by a long way, if you can't use `idevicesyslog` with a simulator.

Comment: `xcrun simctl spawn booted log stream --level=debug` works for me! The other answers such as system.log does *not* show logs of my app

Comment: I've started using Logger in Swift to log info messages. I don't see them in Console.app. What I do see is some system events for the simulator I'm running when I launch the app. How do I see these Logger info messages? Is there a document that explains how to do this?

Comment: Not sure when this may have changed, but using Xcode 14.3.1 and a simulator running iOS 17, the `xcrun simctl spawn booted log collect` outputted: `Archive successfully written to /Users/<user>/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/<simulator_guid>/system_logs.logarchive` which allowed me to open the results. The output from `xcrun simctl getenv booted SIMULATOR_SHARED_RESOURCES_DIRECTORY` was `/Users/<user>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/<simulator_guid>/data`. Spent a few minutes confused because I couldn't find the log file as I was in the wrong directory.

Answer (score 26):

**Apple logs**

[[iOS Logger]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64786306/4770877)

You can use the `Console` application(select your device in Devices) on your Mac to see a log message that were sent using `NSLog`, `os_log`, `Logger` (you will not see logs from `print` function).

Also please check (Action -> Include <Info/Debug> Messages)

[image]

Please note that if you want to see a log from `WebView`(`UIWebView` or `WKWebView`) you should use Safari Web Inspector

```
Device
- Settings -> Safari -> Advanced -> <check in> Web Inspector
Mac
- Safari -> Settings -> Advanced -> <check in> Show Develop menu in menu bar
- Develop -> <device>
```

[[Find crash log]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62213419/4770877)

Comment: press `cmd` `then` `space bar`  Type "`Console`" press `enter`. Btw. that should be the correct answer today.

Comment: This is the only true solution to get all logs of your simulator compared to logcat on Android.

Answer (score 21):

If you are using **Swift**, remember that `println` will only print to the debug log (which appears in xCode's debug area). If you want to print to system.log, you have to use `NSLog` as in the old days.

Then you can view the simulator log via its menu, Debug > Open System Log... (cmd + /)

Answer (score 12):

tailing `/var/log/system.log` didn't work for me. I found my logs by using `Console.app`. They were in
 
`~/Library/Logs/iOS Simulator/{version}/system.log`

Comment: This is a great method to look back at logs from, e.g. days ago.

Answer (score 7):

**XCode > 6.0 AND iOS > 8.0**
The below script works if you have XCode version > 8.0

I use the below small Script to tail the simulator logs onto the system console.

```
#!/bin/sh
sim_dir=`xcrun instruments -s | grep "iPhone 6 (8.2 Simulator)" | awk {'print $NF'} | tr -d '[]'`
tail -f ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/$sim_dir/system.log
```

You can pass in the simulator type used in the Grep as an argument. As mentioned in the above posts, there are simctl and instruments command to view the type of simulators available for use depending on the Xcode version.
To View the list of available devices/simulators.

```
xcrun instruments -s
```

OR

```
xcrun simctl list
```

Now you can pass in the Device code OR Simulator type as an argument to the script and replace the "iPhone 6 (8.2 Simulator)" inside grep to be $1

Answer (score 3):

In Xcode:
View->Debug Area->Activate Console

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can see the Simulator console window, including Safari Web Inspector and all the Web Development Tools by using the Safari Technology Preview app.
Open your page in Safari on the Simulator and then go to Safari Technology Preview > Develop > Simulator.

[image: Web Development Tools]

Comment: where is `Safari Technology Preview` ?

Comment: @cyrf https://developer.apple.com/safari/resources/

Answer (score 0):

I can open the log directly via the iOS simulator: `Debug -> Open System Log...` Not sure when this was introduced, so it might not be available for earlier versions.

Answer (score 0):

No `NSLog` or `print` content will write to `system.log`, which can be open by Select `Simulator -> Debug -> Open System log` on Xcode 11.

I figure out a way, write logs into a file and open the `xx.log` with `Terminal.app`.Then the logs will present in `Terminal.app` lively.

I use [CocoaLumberjack](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack) achieve this.

### STEP 1:

Add `DDFileLogger` `DDOSLogger` and print logs path. `config()` should be called when App lunch.

```swift
static func config() {
    #if DEBUG
    DDLog.add(DDOSLogger.sharedInstance) // Uses os_log
    let fileLogger: DDFileLogger = DDFileLogger() // File Logger
    fileLogger.rollingFrequency = 60 * 60 * 24 // 24 hours
    fileLogger.logFileManager.maximumNumberOfLogFiles = 7
    DDLog.add(fileLogger)
    DDLogInfo("DEBUG LOG PATH: " + (fileLogger.currentLogFileInfo?.filePath ?? ""))
    #endif
}
```

### STEP 2:

Replace `print` or `NSLog` with `DDLogXXX`.

### STEP 3:

```sh
$ tail -f {path of log}
```

Here, message will present in Terminal.app lively.

> One thing more. If there is no any message log out, make sure `Environment Variables` -> `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` ISNOT disable.

Answer (score 0):

My current go-to solution:

```bash
find $(xcrun simctl get_app_container $deviceId $appId data) -name \*.log | xargs tail -f
```

where `appId` is the application identifier, and `deviceId` is the device identifier (usually `booted`).

The `find` command allows for some flexibility in logging libraries, which don't always log to `system.log`.

Answer (score -1):

Download the safari technology review.  With the simulator running, select develop > simulator > localhost

Answer (score -3):

The easiest way to see the console logs is by adding `consolelogs` as a param:

`ionic cordova run ios -l --consolelogs`

And you'll able to see the console logs in your terminal.