# Find crash logs on iOS 8 device

Tags: ios8, crash-dumps

Crash logs used to be accessible through the Settings app. I can't find that in iOS 8. Where did that go?
It's not gone now is it.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I found it. It moved, it's no longer inside General/Diagnostics... It's in Privacy/Diagnostics.

Comment: Long press to Select All no longer works. One now needs to master the art of pulling the right selector and press-scroll all the way down.

Comment: iOS 10.3 and higher. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43799289/292145 below

Answer (score 17):

Start by opening up the Settings app.

- Navigate to Settings - Privacy - Diagnostics & usage - Diagnostics &
  usage Data
- Tap on the crash and you will see a text field with a crash log. Long
  press to Select All and then Copy the crash text.
- Paste it into something you can get off of your device (for example,
  an email to yourself).

Comment: Long press no longer pops "Select All" as an option. In fact, after 10 minutes of experimentation, __nothing__ seems to summon that option. This is kind of awful.

Comment: ditto.  same problem now.

Answer (score 17):

If you have `iOS 10.3` or later, go to `Settings > Privacy`, scroll down and tap `Analytics`. Then tap Share `iPhone & Watch Analytics`.

If you have `iOS 10` to `iOS 10.2`, go to `Settings > Privacy > Diagnostics & Usage` and select Automatically Send or Don't Send.

Answer (score 12):

Getting Crash Logs Directly From a Device Without Xcode

Your users can retrieve crash reports from their device and send them to you via email by following these instructions.

(It is not possible to get device console logs directly from a device)

1) Open Settings app

2) Go to Privacy, then Diagnostics & Usage

3) Select Diagnostics & Usage Data

4) Locate the log for the crashed app. The logs will be named in the format:

5) Select the desired log. Then, using the text selection UI select the entire text of the log. Once the text is selected, tap Copy

6) Paste the copied text to Mail and send to an email address as desired
Getting Crash Logs and Console Output From a Device Using Xcode

Even though you won't be able to run the app in Xcode's debugger, Xcode can still give you all the information you need to debug the problem.
Using Xcode 6

1) Plug in the device and open Xcode

2) Choose Window -> Devices from the menu bar

3) Under the DEVICES section in the left column, choose the device

4) To see the device console, click the up-triangle at the bottom left of the right hand panel

5) Click the down arrow on the bottom right to save the console as a file

6) To see crash logs, select the View Device Logs button under the Device Information section on the right hand panel

7) Find your app in the Process column and select the Crash log to see the contents.

8) To save a crash log, right click the entry on the left column and choose "Export Log"

9) Xcode 6 will also list low memory logs here. These will be shown with a Process name "Unknown" and Type "Unknown". You should examine the contents of these logs to determine whether any of these are caused by your app. For more information about low memory logs, see Understanding and Analyzing iOS Application Crash Reports.
Using Xcode 5

1) Plug in the device and open Xcode

2) Open the Organizer window and select the Devices tab

3) Under the DEVICES section in the left column, expand the listing for the device

4) Select Device Logs to see crash logs or select Console to see Console output
Back to Top
Enabling App Store Diagnostic Reporting

Crash logs are automatically collected from customers who have opted in to sending diagnostic and usage information to Apple.

Beginning with Xcode 6.3, crash logs from App Store customers running at least iOS 8.3 and TestFlight beta testers can be found in the Xcode Organizer. To obtain these crash logs:

1) Open the Organizer window in Xcode 6.3 and above

2) Select "Crashes" at the top. The available crash logs can then be found within this window.

The App Distribution Guide contains further information about the Crash Reporting service.

Crash reports from customers running older iOS versions may be found in iTunes Connect.

If someone is reporting a crash, and you do not see a corresponding report in iTunes Connect, you should direct them to the following knowledge base articles for Mac or for Windows so they can opt-in to sending you crash reports.
Back to Top

Comment: The Xcode instructions worked for me. The important diff b/t this and what I'd found online is that, at least in Xcode 6, you need Window > Devices, not Window > Organizer, to find the crash logs.

Answer (score 1):

iOS 13.4.1

Using iPhone

```
Settings -> Privacy -> Analytics & Improvements -> Analytics Data -> <app_name>
```

Using MacOS

```
~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/<device_name>/<app_name>
```

Using Xcode

```
Window -> Devices and Simulators -> <device_name> -> View Device Logs -> All Logs -> <app_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

When your app crashes, Xcode will enter the debugger and show you more information about the crash:The most important parts are:

**The red arrow**

The red arrow displays which line of code crashed & why it crashed.

**The debugger console**

Many crashes log more information to the debugger console. It should automatically appear when the app crashes, but if it’s not there, show the debugger by selecting the button in the top-right corner of Xcode, and show the console by clicking the button in the bottom-right corner of the debugger.

**The stack trace**

The stack trace lists the functions the program came from before it got to the code that crashed.

Part of the stack trace is displayed in the Debug Navigator on the left of the screen, and the debugger controls allow you to select a stack frame to view in the debugger:

[image]

If you enter the bt command at the (lldb) prompt in the debugger and press return , you will get a textual representation of the stack trace that you can copy and paste:

[image]

Ref:https://medium.com/@javedmultani16/finding-information-about-a-crash-ios-642902134469