# Xcode not showing logs after exiting the app and come back

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I'm using Xcode 6.1 and running an app on the Simulator. When the app exits by double-tap home button, no logs show any more from Xcode console when I come back to the app. Anyone knows what's going on. Appreciate

Comment: is the app exited (i.e. X'd out or terminated) or is it merely put into the background and then eventually brought back to the foreground?

Comment: It's terminated. Double-tapped home and then swiped up.

Comment: @VaibhavMule Please only suggest more substantial edits. Single word edits such as you made [here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7751687) are pointless.

Answer (score 1):

You need to launch (run) the app from Xcode into the simulator in order to get Xcode's debugger to attach and stream the simulator's console output into the debugger window.

You can also view the Simulator console output by looking at a system log file, [details for which can be found in this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165641/how-can-i-get-the-console-logs-from-the-ios-simulator).

Comment: It is also possible to access log files from past debugging sessions through the Report navigator in Xcode 6 (the shortcut for that is ⌘8).

Comment: Maybe this is the only way. Wonder if the app exits it will disconnect with Xcode even if we bring it back.