# When exactly does the UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey get populated?

Tags: ios

When does a custom URL get populated in `launchOptions` in the `AppDelegate.m` file? I've loaded my apps' custom URL in Safari and `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey` is not populated.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{    

    NSLog(@"app launch options");
    NSLog([launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey gets populated when you try to open the app by means of:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"yourapp://"]];
```

...and `yourapp` is [not running](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW3).

Then
`(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *):didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)` will get executed and `NSDictionary` will get populated with two key-values
`UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey`and `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsSourceApplicationKey`

Comment: What's the best way to see my NSLog if I terminate my app and then launch it again in xcode? Also, does the launchOptions not get populated when it comes from safari?

Comment: If your are running the app in a real device. Window->Devices and there you can see the console log of your device.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165641/how-can-i-get-the-console-logs-from-the-ios-simulator You can also use Console.app from your mac and open ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/<simulator-hash>/system.log

Answer (score 2):

The main entry point for any C derived program is a function called `main`, and in ObjC it's called `int main`. This kicks of a series of events that ultimately calls the `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method that ultimately leads to the user getting to see the first "screen" you want them to see.

**2** things will happen after `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` in the next series of events.

1. **If** there is a populated URL key it will use that URL key and call applicationDidBecomeActive:.
2. If there is **not** a URL key set it will then call `application: openURL: sourceURL: annotation` which is where you would set it.

That does leave an issue of how it is populated for the initial call in `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. I believe you can set this in the info.list file.