# Custom event in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, event-handling, custom-controls, xamarin.forms

I was trying to add a custom event to my custom control in Xamarin.Forms. Please take a look at the code below:

```
public delegate void ImageSelectedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
public static event ImageSelectedHandler OnImageSelected;

private void OnImageBtnTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (OnImageSelected != null) 
   {
        OnImageSelected(sender,e);
   }
}
```

In the page which is using the control:

```
SelectMultipleBasePage<ListItems>.OnImageSelected += ListPage_OnImageSelected;

void ListPage_OnImageSelected(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //code here
}
```

I could access the event by using the above code. But I would like to use the control on different pages. On different pages different `OnImageSelected` even will behave differently. And hence I would like to have something like this:

```
SelectMultipleBasePage<ListItems> multiPage = new SelectMultipleBasePage<ListItems>(items);
multiPage.OnImageSelected += ListPage_OnImageSelected;
```

But when I do that I get error:

> Cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

What am I doing wrong in accessing the event?

Comment: By making the event static ! u r making it local to this class only ,
when u want to access it in another class .
u will have to access it as   Myclassname.OnImageSelected

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `static`.

```
public event ImageSelectedHandler OnImageSelected;
```

Then you can call

```
SelectMultipleBasePage<ListItems> multiPage = new SelectMultipleBasePage<ListItems>(items);
multiPage.OnImageSelected += ListPage_OnImageSelected;
```

Of course you have to change the static call, too.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. It gives me error:  `Error 14 Cannot access a non-static member of outer type 'AppName.SelectMultipleBasePage<T>' via nested type 'AppName.SelectMultipleBasePage<T>.WrappedItemSelectionTemplate'

Comment: Could you please look at the my previous question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36714348/how-to-create-an-event-for-custom-control/36724924#36724924)

Comment: you can't use static events if you want to use multiple instances of this control.

Comment: added answer to your other question.