# How to debug an app run from the iOS simulator directly? (not from xcode run)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, ios-simulator

we all know that if we build and run an app from XCode, we can see all the debugging, but what if we want to debug an app preinstalled on iPhone Simulator, I can't seem to find a way to do this, is this possible? how?

I tried [iOS Console](https://lemonjar.com/iosconsole/), but it doesn't seem to even work, the beta has expired.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best way for me was

```
tail -f /Users/userName/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/appID/system.log
```

it prints all data into mac terminal even though if you are not running the app from XCode or something, I wish I knew that before...

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to see the log output (e.g. NSLog()), see the following answer explaining where to find the simulator's system.log file.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10165649

Note that if you are using Swift, "print" statements will not be written to the log file; they will only be displayed in Xcode's console.