# Accessing Props Value Inside Constructor

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using the following code to try and set the initial state by accessing the props value. I thought I could do it by accessing the (props) value but It seems to be empty.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    //this.renderRowForMain = this.renderRowForMain.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      show: props.showModal,
    };

  }
```

if I simply place the following insider the render() then it seems to be loading fine.

```
this.state = {
          show: this.props.showModal,
        };
```

What I am trying to do is initially set the showModal state to true and then when a close button is tapped change the state to false.

Comment: it looks like initially the `prop showModel` is blank or not having the value, to check that use `console.log(props.showModel)` inside `constructor` and see the result.

Comment: Inside the IOS simulator how do I access console.log?

Comment: don't know about that, you can use alert also. check this, how to check console in ios simulator: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165641/how-can-i-get-the-console-logs-from-the-ios-simulator

Comment: in the simulator, hit command + D then you can access the console through the chrome window

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should pass in the `showModal` value in your parent component. Otherwise `props.showModal` will not show up in your constructor.
​

For example: `<MyComponent showModal={true} />`
​
Then, you'll be able to see:
​

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      show: props.showModal, // true
    };
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

First of all use props data in constructor like this..

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.state = {
  show: props.showModal, // true
  };
}
```

then suppose you want to click button and display state data ...so that we should create click function as like

```
onClick(){
console.log(this.state.show);  //display show variable data in state in console
}
```

Whenever you click button then display data in console

And create a button

```
<button className="button" onClick={() => this.onClick()}>Click Me</button>
```