# Getting IOS console from Capacitor

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, capacitor

Does anyone know how to view `console.log()` from the Xcode simulator using capacitor? I am aware that you can view the system logs via iOS Simulator > Menu Bar > Debug > Open System Log ([How can I get the console logs from the iOS Simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165641/how-can-i-get-the-console-logs-from-the-ios-simulator)), but this does not show any of the console.logs when using capacitor to run an ios application.

Comment: open safari go to `devtool`

Comment: Do you mean the website devtool or an feature in safari called devtool? Because I don't see anything native to safari that's called devtool. There is a tab in safari called "develop", if that's what you mean. Would you mind elaborating @NajamUsSaqib?

Comment: Check this: https://ionicframework.com/docs/troubleshooting/debugging#ios-and-safari

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the Ionic instructions to give any output via Safari's dev tools.

However, Capacitor's solution is its built-in Console API https://capacitorjs.com/docs/v2/apis/console

> The Console API automatically sends console.debug, console.error,
> console.info, console.log, console.trace and console.warn calls to the
> native log system on each respective platform. This enables, for
> example, console.log calls to be rendered in the Xcode and Android
> Studio log windows.

I was able to see the logs in Xcode's logging as long as the build isnt broken in some way.